# How to add button control on Azure DevOps workitems page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have to develop AzureDevOps Extension for adding button control on the workitem form page and on click of the button need to show the html pop up window. I have been following the link https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/button#basic-buttons for buttons and pop up window as provided in the link I have used

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "azure-devops-ui/Button";
import { ButtonGroup } from "azure-devops-ui/ButtonGroup";
```

Sample mock-up what I want to achieve:
[image: design to be displayed on workitem page]

On click of the Submit button following pop up has to be shown

[image]

When user enter details, user name has to be filled in the User Name field in the first window.

Pls suggest whether it is possible to add design as shown using AzureDevOps Extension on workitem page?

Comment: Please check whether my answer could help you. If you encounter any issues or difficulties along the way, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi @JaneMa-MSFT, Thank you for the answer, I will try it out and update.

Answer (score 0):

The features you want should have a chance to be implemented. I found a extension called [Action Button Control](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AviHadad.Action-Button). Its [Readme](https://github.com/avih75/Action_Button_Control#custom-control-for-the-work-item-form) details how to add buttons to work items page.

The following steps are for your reference:

1. [Export the work item type definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=azure-devops-2020#how-to-run-the-witadmin-command-line-tool).
2. Change the work item type definition. Click [WebLayout and Control elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops) for detailed information.
3. Write the actions you want to implement. Click [Add a custom control to the work item form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/custom-control?view=azure-devops) for detailed information.
4. [Import your work item type definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=azure-devops-2020#how-to-run-the-witadmin-command-line-tool).